# Cambiar texto dependiendo el enlace

Tags: texto

cómo están. Estoy intentando cambiar el texto desde un botón de una pagina html a otra. Ej: pag1.html:

```
<a href="pag3.html" id="estimate">SOLICITAR PRESUPUESTO</a>
```

pag2.html:

```
<a href="pag3.html" id="permission">SOLICITAR PERMISO</a>
```

pag3.html:

```
<h1 class="contact-text">Este texto debe cambiar dinamicamente en funcion del botón</h1>
```

Acá el js:

```
const contactText = document.querySelector('.contact-text');
const estimate = document.querySelector('#estimate'); 
const permission = document.querySelector('#permission');

estimate.onclick = () => {
  contactText.innerHTML = '¿Qué paquete te gustaría? ¡Te paso presupuesto del que más te interese!';
};

permission.onclick = () => {
  contactText.innerHTML = '¡Escribime y te mando el material que necesites!';
};
```

El problema es que como se linkea a una nueva pagina (pag3) el contenido se recarga y no puedo cambiar el texto según el enlace.

Comment: ¿En la página 3 existen los nodos con `id="permission"` y `id="estimate"`?

Comment: pregunta como te mueves de la pagina 1 o 2 a la 3???

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez cómo estás. En principio tiene un href, quizas sea conveniente resolverlo con window.location.href el redireccionamiento

Comment: si estas pasando con un href debes pasar por la url o por algun metodo el contenido que esperas en la pag 3 no existe manera de que en la pagina lo haga de manera adivinatoria...

Comment: Claro, lo pensé. Pero ambos string son demasiado largos. Desconozco si existe alguna manera de enmascarar la ruta para que no quede todo el string concatenado. @FranciscoNúñez

Comment: puedes establecer dos variables en pagina 3 que contengan los textos...

Comment: luego en la pagina 1 y pagina 2 pones que al dar click pase una simple variable... y esa variable le asignas el numero de la pagima de donde procede

Comment: pag1. html seria valos 1 y pag2. html seriael valor 2

Comment: entonces en pagina 3 puedesdeterminar de donde viene y para cada una usar el texto... un poco ortodoxo pero es la manera rapida de hacer o como se me. ocurre hacerlo...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez muchísimas gracias por todo. Disulpame la demora en responder. Estuve bastante complicado estas últimas semanas y se me pasó revisar los mensajes. Voy a resolverlo como me decís, no lo había pensado así que me biene bárbaro. Muchas gracias!